# What is the "death"? If Gentiles keep Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, gentiles, capital-punishment

What is the death?  Physically? Or spiritually?
A gentile who abstains from melacha is liable to death as it says "day and night they shall not stop" (sanhedrin 58b)

Comment: Not physically.

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed in the Gemara in Sanhedrein 58b-59a

Basically, if Gentiles keep Shabbat they cannot be put to death since they didn't **do** anything - and we never kill people for not doing something.

So it must mean some type of heavenly punishment.

Comment: I thought a transgression of kibud av va'em was liable for the death penalty? (Although we never did kill anyone for it...)

Comment: @SAH - I have no idea what you're talking about or what this has to do with this question. (There's a death penalty for injuring parents.)

Comment: so not for a lack of kibud av va'em (which would be "not doing something")?

Comment: @SAH - correct.